# What board game does this die belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I found a red and black die in my pocket. The sides are a T, a Roman column, two people, a clock with x2, one person, and another T; each image is bordered by a circle. I have no idea what it's from; any help?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange!

Comment: If you could get a picture of a few of the sides, that might help things.

Comment: What's more concerning is that you just found them in your pocket.

Comment: @corsiKa If I ever work at a coat check, I'm going to surreptitiously slip random board game dice into people's pockets. What a great idea!

Answer (score 25):

The die belongs to the 2013 version of [Taboo](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1111/taboo), which added the new "game-changer die". You can see it in the picture below along with the other components of the game:

[image: Taboo 2013 game components]

As a game variation, you can roll the die before each round and have a chance to play with an alternate rule

- **T:** Play with standard Taboo rules
- **Roman Column:** You must be perfectly still, like a statue, while giving the clues. The person with the buzzer must turn the cards for you.
- **Two People:** Both teams guess as you give the clues, but still give tallies separately
- **Clock x2:** You get double the time and turn over the timer the first time it runs out.
- **One person:** Only one person can guess during the round, instead of your whole team.